# contextual system of congruences

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

A large wholesale company for books uses three different types of shelf in their ware-
houses. Their capacity is gauged in terms of a certain specimen book of average size, known
under the nickname "Dumbbook". Shelves of type A can accommodate 56 Dumbbooks, the
ones of type B only 45 Dumbbooks, while the extra large type C shelves hold 121 Dumbbooks.
Upon receiving a certain batch of books (assumed to be Dumbbooks), the workers first put
them into shelves of type A, filling a certain number of shelves exactly and leaving 11 books
left over. They then try to t the books into shelves of type B, filling a certain number of
shelves exactly and leaving space for 23 books on the last shelf. Finally they try to t the
books into shelves of type C, filling a certain number of shelves exactly and leaving 4 books
left over. What is the number of books, assuming all batches have at most 10000 books?

I have summarised this into the system of congruences:

x = 11 mod 56

x = 23 mod 45

x = 4 mod 121

and I get the solution to be 183803 mod 304920, which I have checked and seems correct. However, this is clearly below 10000, and since gcd(56,45,121) = 1, I believe this means there is a unique solution. Does this mean that there are no appropriate solutions? Or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong is in reading the statements.

"... and *leaving space for* 23 books on the last shelf" means the second equation (for shelf B) should read
$$
x = -23 \mod 45
$$
Redo your work with this different second equation and I think you will find that the solution comes out to be less that 10,000.